# Opencv cannot open camera device when running as a service on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

Something is preventing Opencv (4.5.1 last commit) to open camera device if there is no UX session active, for example, if the process is running as a system service on Ubuntu.

I am trying to run my program as a service on Ubuntu 20.04. When the process try to open the camera:

```
cv::VideoCapture camera;
camera.open(0);
```

fails with message:

```
/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (890) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
```

The program open the camera without errors if I perform a loggin in the UX. However, the program cannot open the device if I am logged only by ssh (and I'm not logged in the UX). On ssh I can see the device there:

```
d$ ls -ls /dev/video0
0 crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 fev 24 14:16 /dev/video0
```

So, how to make opencv open the device if the program is running as a service?

EDIT:

As a workaround, I managed to open the camera running the service with `sudo`. It is not a great solution because means that I need to run the program with admin rights. Anyway, It suggests that the problem is caused by some permission issue.

Comment: I have a very similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462131/opencv-cant-capture-frames-on-production-server-nginx-uwsgi

Could you show the code of how you run your service with ```sudo```?